# textual analysis and statistical analysis using Hadoop on json or unstructured data extracted from web

Tags: hadoop, sentiment-analysis, text-analysis, flume-ng

Im am extracting data from web , converting it into a json form and then storing it into hadoop fs using apache flume. So flume makes its our files when storing data on hadoop. Now i want to access this data randomly and so text analysis or statistical analysis on it. What can be the optimal way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "real time analysis"? Since the data is already in HDFS...are you considering Apache Spark?

Comment: yeah that was  a mistake (real time), i don't have an experience of spark, i have configured a spark cluster on yarn, how can i do that on spark